# Google maps Marker refresh with an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I tried to refresh my markers on the map. For this i tried to push the markers into an array. Google Maps continues adding markers but not deleting the old ones. Is the array correcly implemented? What's wrong with my code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xyzs&sensor=true">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map;
      var markersArray = [];
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.137, 11.577),
          zoom: 14,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);
      }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>    
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function() {
      function deleteOverlays() {
  if (markersArray) {
    for (i in markersArray) {
      markersArray[i].setMap(null);
    }
    markersArray.length = 0;
  }
}
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON('./url.php', function(data) {
          var cars = data.rec.vehicles.vehicles;
          $.each(cars, function(key, data) {
            var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.position.latitude, data.position.longitude); 
            var imageh = data.model;
            var bild = "/" + imageh + ".png";
            if(data.fuelState <=25)
              {bild="/EMPTY.png";}
            var bild1= "/" + imageh + "1.png";
            var tanken1="";
            if(data.fuelState<=25){tanken1="TANKEN";}
            var drive="Manuell";
            if(data.auto=="Y"){drive="Automatik";}
            var kosten="31 Cent/Minute"
            if(data.model=="BMW 1er Cabrio"){kosten="34 Cent/Minute"}
            if(data.model=="MINI Cabrio"){kosten="34 Cent/Minute"}
            if(data.model=="BMW X1 "){kosten="34 Cent/Minute"}
            console.log(bild);
            console.log(data.auto);
            console.log(drive);
            console.log(kosten);
            console.log(markersArray);
            var contentString ='<h1>'+data.model+" "+data.carName+'</h1><IMG BORDER="0" ALIGN="center" SRC="' + data.model + '1.png"><br><br>Kennzeichen: '+ data.licensePlate +'<br>Fahrgestellnummer: '+data.vin+'<br>Getriebe: '+drive+'<br>Fuellstand: ' + data.fuelState + '% <IMG BORDER="0" ALIGN="absmiddle" SRC="' + data.fuelState + '.png"><br>Zustand: <IMG BORDER="0" align="absmiddle" SRC="' + data.innerCleanliness + '.png"><br>Adresse:  ' +data.address+'<br>Kosten: '+kosten+'<br><a href="https://de.drive-now.com/php/metropolis/vehicle_details?vin='+ data.vin +'">Dieses Fahrzeug jetzt Buchen!</a><br><br><IMG BORDER="0" ALIGN="center" SRC="/dnlogo.jpg">';

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString
            });
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: LatLng,
                title: data.model,
                icon: bild
            });
            markersArray.push(marker);
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function()  {
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {if(infowindow){infowindow.close();}});
            });

            marker.setMap(map);
          });
        });
      });
      }, 2000);

      $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON('./PetrolStations.txt', function(data) {
          $.each(data, function(key, data) {
            var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng); 
            var bild1 = "/PETROL.png";
            var contentString1 = data.name;
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString1
            });
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: LatLng,
                title: data.lng,
                icon: bild1
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function()  {
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {if(infowindow){infowindow.close();}});
            });

            marker.setMap(map);
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please try to alert() the markersArray[i] components inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined the function `deleteOverlays()`, but you forgot to call it somewhere.