# Blink particular Marker on Google Maps for time interval

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I got my refreshing markers working. I pushed the markers into an array and deleted the entrys. Now the markers blinking on every refresh. Is it possible to do this without blinking?

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBWNV9u4tYWoY-nHa6X3x4olm6ZehLqzls&sensor=true">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map;
      var markersArray = [];
      var newMarkersArray = [];
      var petrolmarkers = [];
      var tankstelle;
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.137, 11.577),
          zoom: 14,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);
      }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>    
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var zeit = "1000";
    setInterval(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON('./url.php', function(data) {
          deleteOverlays();
          var cars = data.rec.vehicles.vehicles;
          $.each(cars, function(key, data) {
            var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.position.latitude, data.position.longitude); 
            var imageh = data.model;
            var bild = "/" + imageh + ".png";
            if(data.fuelState <=25)
              {bild="/EMPTY.png";}
            var bild1= "/" + imageh + "1.png";
            var tanken1="";
            if(data.fuelState<=25){tanken1="TANKEN";}
            var drive="Manuell";
            if(data.auto=="Y"){drive="Automatik";}
            var kosten="31 Cent/Minute"
            var tankstelle ="";
            if(data.model=="BMW 1er Cabrio"){kosten="34 Cent/Minute"}
            if(data.model=="MINI Cabrio"){kosten="34 Cent/Minute"}
            if(data.model=="BMW X1 "){kosten="34 Cent/Minute"}
            console.log(bild);
            console.log(data.auto);
            console.log(drive);
            console.log(kosten);
            console.log(markersArray);
            console.log(petrolmarkers);
            find_closest_marker(data.position.langitude,data.position.longitude);
            var contentString ='<h1>'+data.model+" "+data.carName+'</h1><IMG BORDER="0" ALIGN="center" SRC="' + data.model + '1.png"><br><br>Kennzeichen: '+ data.licensePlate +'<br>Fahrgestellnummer: '+data.vin+'<br>Getriebe: '+drive+'<br>Fuellstand: ' + data.fuelState + '% <IMG BORDER="0" ALIGN="absmiddle" SRC="' + data.fuelState + '.png"><br>Zustand: <IMG BORDER="0" align="absmiddle" SRC="' + data.innerCleanliness + '.png"><br>Adresse:  ' +data.address+'<br>Kosten: '+kosten+'<br><a href="https://de.drive-now.com/php/metropolis/vehicle_details?vin='+ data.vin +'">Dieses Fahrzeug jetzt Buchen!</a><br><br><IMG BORDER="0" ALIGN="center" SRC="/dnlogo.jpg">'+tankstelle;
            //find_closest_marker(data.position.langitude,data.position.longitude);
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString
            });
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: LatLng,
                title: data.model,
                icon: bild
            });
            newMarkersArray.push(marker);

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function()  {
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {if(infowindow){infowindow.close();}});
            });

            marker.setMap(map);
          });
        });
      });
      removeMarkers(markersArray);
      markersArray = newMarkersArray;
      newMarkersArray = [];
      }, zeit);

      $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON('./PetrolStations.txt', function(data) {
          $.each(data, function(key, data) {
            var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng); 
            var bild1 = "/PETROL.png";
            var contentString1 = data.name;
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString1
            });
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: LatLng,
                title: data.name,
                icon: bild1
            });
            petrolmarkers.push(marker);
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function()  {
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {if(infowindow){infowindow.close();}});
            });

            marker.setMap(map);
          });
        });
      });
     function removeMarkers(array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i].setMap(null);
    }
}



    function deleteOverlays() {
    if (markersArray) {
    for (i in markersArray) {
      markersArray[i].setMap(null);
    }
    markersArray.length = 0;
  }
}
function find_closest_marker( lat1, lon1 ) {

var pi = Math.PI;
var R = 6371; //equatorial radius
var distances = [];
var closest = -1;

for( i=0;i<petrolmarkers.length; i++ ) {

    var lat2 = petrolmarkers[i].getPosition().lat();
    var lon2 = petrolmarkers[i].getPosition().lng();

    var chLat = lat2-lat1;
    var chLon = lon2-lon1;


    var dLat = chLat*(pi/180);
    var dLon = chLon*(pi/180);

    var rLat1 = lat1*(pi/180);
    var rLat2 = lat2*(pi/180);

    var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
            Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.cos(rLat1) * Math.cos(rLat2); 
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
    var d = R * c;


    distances[i] = d;
    if ( closest == -1 || d < distances[closest] ) {
        closest = i;
        console.log(closest);
        tankstelle=closest;
    }

}}
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: SO is not a private help-center. When you [delete your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462737/google-maps-marker-refresh-with-an-array/18463658) as soon as you get an answer, this will not have any benefit for the community. So you may either stop deleting your questions or stop expecting that you get answers.

Comment: okay ... sry for that :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also found the flicker to be pretty annoying, so to minimize it I add the new markers to the map first, and then remove the old ones.

Of course this won't work if the items on the map are changing position - in my case I was displaying stationary units as they turned on and off so having 2 markers for one object was not an issue.

1 - Have two marker arrays: markerArray and newMarkerArray.

2 - Make the ajax call to get the new maker data.

3 - Add the new markers to the map and then add them to newMarkerArray.

4 - Remove the old markers.

5 - Set markerArray to newMarkerArray.

6 - Reset newMarkerArray back to an empty array.

This a pretty condensed version, I only included the relevant parts:

```
<script type ="text/javascript">

var newMarkerArray = [];
var markerArray = [];

$(document).ready(function () {
    setMarkers();
    var intervalId = setInterval(function () {
        setMarkers();
    }, 5000);
});

function setMarkers() {
    $.ajax({
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    //Add new marker to map
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ map: map });
                    newMarkerArray.push(marker);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    removeMarkers(markerArray);
    markerArray = newMarkerArray;
    newMarkerArray = [];
}

function removeMarkers(array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i].setMap(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks ... see my edited code at the top... i implemented your suggestion ... but it wont work ... why? :)

Comment: You need to change markersArray.push(marker); to NewMarkersArray.push(marker);

Comment: still flickering ... but they show off lot shorter than before :/

Comment: It's not a perfect solution, but it makes the flicker almost unnoticeable for me.

Comment: Nothing changed for me .. :/ ..my markers still hiding for a moment.. is my code correct in order to you solution?

Answer (score 2):

Well I've just gone through this blinking problem, and I figured out something that worked for me, maybe this will help you.

So, let's say you have to display cars in your map. Just create an array to store the cars data that will actually appear on the map, that will be carsToDisplay.
In order to update carsToDisplay's markers without blinking them (which is caused by erasing its data, then storing new data and only then displaying new markers again), it is a better approach to just set the markers position based on the carsUpdatedFromElsewhere markers (this one stores the most recent data, but wont show in the map).

First method you need to call will be loadCars(), and it will fill carsToDisplay with the information you need to display from carsUpdatedElsewhere, and then loadCars() calls carsRefreshed (this one has an interval, which is basically an event that will be called from time to time). In refreshCars(), based on the time interval you specify, carsToDisplay markers will have their position set to the ones in carsUpdatedFromElsewhere, just using .setPosition(lat: number, lng : number).

There you go:

```
var carsToDisplay = [];
var carsUpdatedFromElseWhere = [];

carsRefresher = function() {
    interval = setInterval(function(){
        for(var i = 0; i < carsUpdatedFromElseWhere.length; i++){
            carsToDisplay[i].setPosition({
                lat: carsUpdatedFromElseWhere[i].lat,
                lng: carsUpdatedFromElseWhere[i].lng
            });
        }   
    }, 1000);
}

loadCars = function(){
    for(var i=0; i < carsUpdatedFromElseWhere.length;i++){
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {
                lat : carsUpdatedFromElseWhere[i].lat,
                lng : carsUpdatedFromElseWhere[i].lng
            },
            map: map, //assuming you have a global map variable
            /*
                you may set other properties here
            */
        });
        carsToDisplay.push(marker);
    }
    carsRefresher();
}

loadCars();
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your markers Optimize option to false!!! new google.maps.Marker({ map: map, **optimized:false**, zIndex:IndexCount++,
I benchmarked my script (in IE analytics) with and without optimized markers; I saw a massive reduction in resource usage, script time etc.